# How to stop an asynchronus task midway

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an `Async` task:

```
private class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = "";

        try{
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),0);
            curVersionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (Exception Ignored) {

        }
        result = check(curVersionCode);
        return result;
    }

 ...


  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String success){
        if (success != "a") this.cancel(true); //Here's the confusion
        switch (success){
            case "z":
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setMessage("0").setCancelable(true).show();
                break;
            case "a":
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setMessage("1").setCancelable(true).show();
                break;
            default:new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setMessage("default").setCancelable(true).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

I want to stop the Asynctask if success is `!=a`. How to achieve that?

It is possible to let it continue and switch through only if `success == a` and break otherwise. What will be best - let it continue or cancel the task midway?

Comment: If the code in onPostExecute() runs than doInBackground is finished(). So the AsyncTask has stopped then. It does not have to be cancelled anymore. Does not make sense.

Comment: what is the point of a switch(success) if you break when sucess !=a ?  you will only perform the switch(success) if success="a" so there is only one possible case, which means the switch is redundant.

Comment: No the switch is not redundant. But the cancel has no effect.

Comment: You better change to `if (success != "a") return;` if you dont wanna execute the rest of the code.

Comment: ok. I can perceive it now. Thanks.

Comment: @greenapps thanks. This is what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code in onPostExecute() runs than doInBackground is finished().

So the AsyncTask has stopped then.

It does not have to be cancelled anymore.

Does not make sense.

Comment: But how to cancel if i want? This was the question. It's answer should be added.

Comment: If you want to cancel an asynctask then you can do that in a button onClick with `updateApp.cancel()`

Comment: no i dont want any button. I just need to cancel it silently. `if (success != "a") return;`, as you commented.  This is what i needed.

Comment: Well what you want is not called "canceling an asynctask" but instead "doing nothing in onPostExecute() if a result has a certain value. And it is not midway but at the end in onPostExecute.

Comment: May be. That was how it came to me.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `OBJECT_OF_ASYNK_TASK.cancel();` 
In Android Studio explanation of this method is give check that for more information

```
 class Temp extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}

private void runTemp(){
    Temp temp =   new Temp();
    temp.execute();
    temp.cancel(true);
}
```